# cannot resolve method `setLatestEventInfo`

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I making Reminder app but I get cannot resolve method `setLatestEventInfo` method.

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        NotifyService getService() {
            return NotifyService.this;
        }
    }

    private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
    public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "com.example.seng.healthyapp.INTENT_NOTIFY";
    private NotificationManager mNM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))
            showNotification();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    private void showNotification() {

        CharSequence title = "Alarm!!";
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;

        CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us.";
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, text, time);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, text, contentIntent);

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
        NotifyService getService() {
            return NotifyService.this;
        }
    }

    private static final int NOTIFICATION = 123;
    public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "com.example.seng.healthyapp.INTENT_NOTIFY";
    private NotificationManager mNM;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
        mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

        if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))
            showNotification();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();

    private void showNotification() {
        CharSequence title = "Alarm!!";

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
        CharSequence text = "Your notification time is upon us.";

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class), 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        Notification notification = builder.build();

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        mNM.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);

        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'setLatestInfo` was removed in API 23: https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.app.Notification.html

You should use the `Notification.Builder` instead: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

There is an example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

I am assuming you're using an outdated Android tutorial. Try to use the ones from https://developer.android.com. They're the most reliable.

Comment: hye, thanks for all the information. I have edited my code based on the example you gave. Can you help me check whether I implemented them in the correct way ?

Comment: the `long` time is never used

Comment: What do you want to use it for?

Comment: I not sure is it because of the `time`. I follow everything from this [tutorial](http://blog.blundellapps.co.uk/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/) but I didn't get any notifications.

Comment: Like I said, try using the tutorial I linked you to instead, then searching the website for any other questions you have instead of using the outdated example.